# How to set a footer section to stay at the bottom unless there is extra content and we need to scroll to see it using flex

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to follow a tutorial in how have a footer that displays at the bottom of the page is there is not enough content to fill the page OR it will stay at the bottom of the content if the content exceeds the viewport.

This page as a couple of alternatives: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

I'm trying to follow the flex one (I thought it was the most modern/simple, correct me if i'm wrong).

I think the only diference in my webapp is that I am also using a navbar from react-bootstrap that might be interfering with my result.

my problem is that when there is not enough content the footer doesnt stick to the bottom.

what am I missing to fix this? I'm open to other aproaches

My main code is:

```
<div className="App"> 
  <div id="home">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" className="Logo"/>
  </div>
  <NavigationBar onSearchChange={OnSearchChange} />
      
  <div className='Content'>
    <button onClick={AddCard}>Add Content</button>
    <ECardList {...{ecards: ecards, filters:filters}} />
  </div>

  <div className='Footer'>
    © Copyright 2010-{(new Date().getFullYear())}
  </div>
</div>
```

and my css is this:

```
.App {
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: url('../images/background.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#Home {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.Logo {
  height: 15vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Content {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.Footer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding-top: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 1);
  height:21px;
  width:100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.navbar {
  box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
              inset 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

and my navigation bar is just one of the examples sticking to the top from react-bootstrap, but i think its the one causing my problem,
this is the complete code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Navbar, Nav, Form, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { INavigationBarProps } from '../../types/INavigationBarProps'

const NavigationBar = (props: INavigationBarProps) => {
  return <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg" sticky="top">
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="mr-auto">
      <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>   
    </Nav>
    <Form inline>
      <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search..." className="mr-sm-2" onChange={props.onSearchChange}/>
    </Form>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
}

export default NavigationBar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your App class the follow:

```
.App{
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```

You need a minimum value in height before the `height: 100%` that you are using.

`100vh` refers to the 100% of the actual viewport height.

Comment: thanks! I spent 4h of trial and error... but this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You're after what's called a *sticky footer*. There are numerous ways to acheive it these days. Here's how to do it with the CSS grid method:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    My header
  </header>
  <main>
    <p>Hello world.</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Footer is on bottom!
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: i think in my example .app is the equivalent of body (because it is wrapping all the other elements) but having height: 100% was not enough, dont know why. min-height solved it to force the 100% size